# Keeping the last row selected of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am inserting every row to the UITable view using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Now I need to always keep the last cell of the table view always selected. i.e. Whenever a new entry is added is should be in selected state and when it is deleted the previous entry of the table view must be in selected state. I tried using `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method but doesn't work out. Any ideas on how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` from [UITableView API](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:) in your methods that do the adding and subtracting after determining which item in your collection should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selected` property of `UITableViewCell`